# 'Upgradation' not universally accepted?

Tags: meaning, orthography, dictionaries, subcontinental-english

While copy-editing an article for a journal, I came across the word “upgradation” underlined red by MS Word (It's underlined red even as I type it in Chrome).

The publishers of the journal recommend following the Oxford dictionary. Now, strangely  [one of Oxford's sites](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/spellcheck/all/?q=upgradation) returns 'No results found for “upgradation”' on searching, while [another](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/upgradation) defines it as 'the fact of upgrading something'.

The [Cambridge dictionary site](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/) also has an entry for the word.

Both, Oxford Learner's Dictionary's site and the Cambridge Dictionary's site are complete with US as well as British pronunciations. As far as I know the word is very much in use at least in Indian English.

I am unable to make sense out of these findings. Please share if you have any idea why there is such a predicament over “upgradation”.

Comment: I've (native American English speaker) never heard of it until now.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect. Some "words" are more "marginal" than others. Not all dictionaries (or native speakers in general) will accept ***upgradation*** as a valid word, obviously. FWIW, OED defines it as ***Indian English** - the raising or improvement of grade, status, or level; = **upgrading***, with first citation 1979. But it would probably be considered just a "mistake" by most non-IE speakers.

Comment: What Telastyn and FumbleF said!  In addition, *upgradation* is, well, ugly -- sounds awful.  Consider avoiding it altogether.  (Just one opinion.)

Comment: Rather than asking  “*Upgradation* not universally accepted?” perhaps you should have asked “*Upgradation* not universally condemned?”

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your comment satisfies my query to a large extent. Had the dictionaries I have mentioned defined the word as Indian English, I might not have sought views on the situation. That both of these dictionaries provided British as well as North American pronunciations added to the confusion.

Comment: @user73747: The Internet is a great leveller, and it remains to be seen how IE will fare over the next few decades. I'm in the UK, where it's very noticeable that IE speakers (normally, "first generation" immigrants) usually make considerable efforts to identify to avoid using "IE-only" speech patterns. Probably in no small measure due to pressure from their *children*, who will obviously want to avoid being mocked at school for not speaking "properly". I think that's the way it will go globally, and that forward-looking IE speakers will increasingly avoid/disown forms like *upgradation*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for the constructive comment. Your observation of the situation of IE out there is exact. Is that not true for other numerous varieties of English? And while emigrants may struggle to shun IE, back here in the Indian sub-continent a good volume of literature in IE continues to be created and read.

Comment: You say that 'The publishers of the journal recommend following the Oxford dictionary.' I doubt this very strongly; they are doubtless aware that Oxford University Press publishes various dictionaries. That they contain different sets of words is hardly surprising: some dictionaries are more comprehensive than others. I'm pretty sure that the correct statement should be 'The publishers of the journal recommend following the **Oxford English Dictionary**.' If OED marks the word as 'Indian English', it should not be used in a journal aimed at other readers.

Comment: @user73747: I think you'd be hard put to find examples of "IE-specific" usages from writers like Salman Rushdie and V.S. Naipaul, if for no other reason than that they want to maximise their "acceptability" to the US/UK/AU readership markets. The forces of globalisation will probably mean that in the end you'll be no more likely to find *books* written in IE than you are currently to find books written in, say, Cockney English. People will continue to *speak* "dialectally" for generations, but writers tend to go for standardisation at that level of language use.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is partly based on the false premise that there is a dictionary called 'The Oxford Dictionary' which exists in various incompatible forms.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is a word that has become established in one variety of English (Indian) but is more or less unknown in other dialects of English. That is really all that can be said.

Comment: Yes, I agree. as far as I know, many speakers or writers from India would say or write 'upgradation of facilities", while most other speakers/writers from around the world (including those from USA and UK) would use "upgrading of facilities".

Comment: and it's hardly Queen's English. Just like using the word "doubt" as a noun when one should use the word "question".

Comment: No, jwenting. Since these uses of "doubt" and "upgradation" appear to be normal parts of Indian English, there is no "should" about it. This is an international site.

Comment: @jwenting Almost nothing is the ‘Queen’s English’ anymore. Even the Queen herself no longer speaks the ‘Queen’s English’. Comparing a word specific to Indian English to an all but extinct variety of English that was never more than a sociolect spoken by a very small elite borders on the nonsensical.

Answer (score 4):

It's an informal word created by informal English users who collectively influence large group of users/people. Most of these words originated from India (eg. upgradation, updation). Basically, it is used by English users (Indians) confidently thus influencing the other non-familiar English user that it is a formal word. With India's population these words had become common through the years. Nevertheless, these words are not formally acceptable to native English users.

Comment: To a native English speaker, all this sounds like some form of [pidgin English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pidgin) generated by non-native speakers.

Answer (score 0):

That's an Indian-English word. Indian English has a life of its own. I would avoid using the word as well as other features of Indian English grammar ( e.g. I am wanting to sleep)

Comment: There is no reason to avoid using Indian English words or constructions if your audience is Indian English-speaking. You might as well advice someone to avoid using words like _lorry_ or _harvestman_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet There is no reason to avoid using pidgin/incorrect/just plain awful English?

Comment: @FaheemMitha There is no reason to avoid pidgin features if your audience is itself pidgin, no. I wouldn’t call Indian English pidgin, though—it’s a group of English dialects influenced by various other substrate languages, just like Hibernian English is.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It's a group of English languages influenced by laziness and ignorance of correct English. Please excuse bile.

Comment: @Faheem Try learning a bit about how languages actually work, then come back. Your comments here are extremely ignorant of language development and evolution.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Try learning a bit about how India actually works, then come back. Your comments here are extremely ignorant of how India actually works. Speaking as an actual Indian, who does.

Comment: @Faheem But this isn’t just about India. This is how language works **everywhere** in the world. All languages and their varieties, no matter where on the planet, are founded upon “laziness and ignorance of correct [language]”. That’s how languages evolve. This example may be Indian, but the principle is universal. (My apologies for coming across rather harsh before—I hadn’t seen your edit to “excuse bile” and thought you were calling my comment bile, which rather riled me. I just saw the edit now, which makes it rather different. Sorry about that.)

Comment: I am an Indian and never have heard of a well educated person say "I am wanting to sleep". Please don't mislead by calling it "Indian English Grammar". @Colin Fine's answer is correct and complete.